# ContentProvider Problems with Phone.DISPLAY_NAME

Tags: android

See code to get all contacts on phone:

```
public ContactInfo[] getContactList(String selection, String[] selectionargs) {

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    };

    String sortOrder = Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
            projection, selection, selectionargs, sortOrder);

    ContactInfo[] contactInfoList = new ContactInfo[cursor.getCount()];
    ContactInfo contactInfo;
    int i=0;

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

        contactInfo = new ContactInfo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)), "");

        String[] projectionPhone = new String[] {
                Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Phone.NUMBER,
                Phone.TYPE,
        };

        Cursor phoneCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                projectionPhone, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + "='" + contactInfo.getName() + "'", null, null);  

        PhoneInfo[] phoneInfoList = new PhoneInfo[phoneCursor.getCount()];

        int j = 0;

        while(phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {

            int type = ContactInfo.TYPE_OTHER;          

            if (phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE)) == Phone.TYPE_HOME)

                type = ContactInfo.TYPE_HOME;

            else if (phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE)) == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE
                    || phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE)) == Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE)

                type = ContactInfo.TYPE_MOBILE;

            else if (phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE)) == Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME
                    || phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE)) == Phone.TYPE_FAX_WORK)

                type = ContactInfo.TYPE_FAX;

            else if (phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE)) == Phone.TYPE_WORK)

                type = ContactInfo.TYPE_OFFICE;

            phoneInfoList[j++] = contactInfo.new PhoneInfo(
                    FWUtil.SeparatesCharacters(phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER))),
                    type);

        }

        phoneCursor.close();


        String[] projectionEMail = new String[] {
                Email.CONTACT_ID,
                Email.DATA,
                Email.TYPE
        };

        Cursor emailCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI, 
                projectionEMail, Email.CONTACT_ID + "='" + contactInfo.getName() + "'", null, null);    

        EmailInfo[] emailInfoList = new EmailInfo[emailCursor.getCount()];

        j = 0;

        while(emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

            int type = ContactInfo.TYPE_OTHER;          

            if (emailCursor.getInt(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(Email.TYPE)) == Email.TYPE_HOME)

                type = ContactInfo.TYPE_HOME;

            else if (emailCursor.getInt(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(Email.TYPE)) == Email.TYPE_MOBILE)

                type = ContactInfo.TYPE_MOBILE;

            else if (emailCursor.getInt(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(Email.TYPE)) == Email.TYPE_WORK)

                type = ContactInfo.TYPE_OFFICE;

            emailInfoList[j++] = contactInfo.new EmailInfo(
                    emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA)),
                    type);

        }

        emailCursor.close();

        contactInfo = new ContactInfo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID)),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)),
                phoneInfoList, emailInfoList, new AddressInfo[0], "");

        contactInfoList[i++] = contactInfo;
    }

    cursor.close();

    return contactInfoList;

    //return new ContactInfo[0];

}`
```

This code get all contacts, but when contact has ' on name, like: 'Jonh. Systems show an exception, I don't know how to replace this charactere, because Android set query and projection before get the data no auto replace ' by "!!!!

```
  09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Jonh": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT contact_id, display_name, data1, data2 FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1 AND mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2') AND (display_name=''Jonh')
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:330)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:7924)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:7909)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkQuery(ContentProvider.java:150)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:111)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
09-30 08:44:19.732: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(9292):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use '?' in your name selection.

context.getContentResolver().query(URI, projection, Email.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { contactInfo.getName()}, null);

Have a try

Answer (score 0):

The `'` in the name is breaking your query-string. Use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

This seams to be a classic [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) case. If you like, create a user named

```
';DROP TABLE [your_table];
```

And see what happens ;)

---

The `query()`-method works *like* a PreparedStatement. Instead of using something like this:

```
Email.CONTACT_ID + "='" + contactInfo.getName() + "'"
```

you should use the parameters which are offered by the method. An example might be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#querying).

Comment: Dear I know this. But, how use prepared statement in Content Providers of Android?